# C# ListView in VirtualMode flickers when the selected item is not visible

Tags: c#, listview, flicker, virtualmode

I know it sounds complicated to reproduce but please follow me:

You have a ListView with `VirtualMode = true.`

Select an item, scroll down so that the item selected gets outside the visual area and then try to add another item to the ListView.

You will see that for a split second it behaves abnormally and see somekind of flicker.
If you escalate the situation and try to add a lot of items really fast (I add around 20 times per second) you will see that the small problem becomes very big. It's a combination of flickering and invalid items around there.

I have investigated the problem and it seems that the ListView generates a lot of `RetrieveVirtualItem` events for the selected item (even though it's clearly not visible).

It seems like when I add a new item (increase VirtualListSize) the ListView first tries to focus on the selected item and then go back to the previous location.

Did anybody experience the same problem?

Answer (score 5):

Here a derived class with workaround this problem.

Use `SetVirtualListSize()` method instead of the regular `VirtualListSize`.

```
public class FlickerFreeListView : ListView
{
    #region Static Functionality

    private static FieldInfo _internalVirtualListSizeField;

    static FlickerFreeListView()
    {
        _internalVirtualListSizeField = typeof(ListView).GetField("virtualListSize", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

        if (_internalVirtualListSizeField == null)
        {
            string msg = "Private field virtualListSize in type System.Windows.Forms.ListView is not found. Workaround is incompatible with installed .NET Framework version, running without workaround.";
            Trace.WriteLine(msg);
        }
    }

    #endregion


    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    internal IntPtr SendMessage(int msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
    {
        return SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), msg, wparam, lparam);
    }

    public void SetVirtualListSize(int size)
    {
        // if workaround incompatible with current framework version (usually MONO)
        if (_internalVirtualListSizeField == null)
        {
            VirtualListSize = size;
        }
        else
        {
            if (size < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("ListViewVirtualListSizeInvalidArgument");
            }

            _internalVirtualListSizeField.SetValue(this, size);
            if ((base.IsHandleCreated && this.VirtualMode) && !base.DesignMode)
            {
                SendMessage(0x102f, new IntPtr(size), new IntPtr(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but it has been a long time since I had the problem. I can't test this solution anymore. I see it has some upvotes so if anyone tested this and it worked then write a comment here so I can accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Various controls have a protected DoubleBuffered property. You could try deriving your own DBListView from ListView, and in its constructor set its DoubleBuffered property to true.

Comment: Since there's been a while since i've posted the question I'll try and find that project and give your solution a try. Thanks

Comment: well? don't keep us in suspense! It's been almost 11 years. Did it work?

Comment: Stil looking for the project.